# Nothing happens when creating a new project in VS2017 on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When I try to create a new project in VS2017 , I select my template and click OK
Nothing happens.

This issue started recently and the problem does not occur if I am running as administrator.

So far I am investigating this link [on registry issues](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/66554/cannot-create-new-project-hit-okay-button-but-noth.html)

I found the advice "Unfortunately the current work-around is to export settings / delete the private registry file / import settings and try again."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huy Nguyen gives the answer at 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/79829/access-denied-when-trying-to-enableinstall-an-exte.html

- Export your current VS settings with Tools | Import and Export Settings… because the next step will lose custom settings and extensions
- (If the registry is corrupted, export settings may fail and we have to ignore this step)
- Delete VS app data: %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_[UniqueID].
- If your account is part of the Administrators group, launch Visual Studio as Administrator once. You can continue to run as Standard User afterwards.
- Otherwise, launch Visual Studio as Standard User.